# PC shutdown unexpectedly without blue screen

Tags: windows, shutdown, bsd

My PC is shutting down after few hours(?) without BSD, but keyboard lights, power LED, fans are running (it's not sleep mood or hibernating). To switch them off I have to switch off the UPS, holding the power button doesn't help. Then the system boots up normally like nothing happened. I checked all the cables and they seem to be fine. I haven't made any hardware or software changes recently.

System Information

OS: Windows 7 32-bit
CPU: Intel E5200 @2.5 dual core
RAM: 2GB Kingston
VGA: Nvidia GT240
MB: Foxconn G31-MXP
HDD: 1 x Samsung HD322HJ, 1 x Toshiba DT01ACA100

Comment: PC make and model?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely heat related. It might be the CPU heatsink paste having dried out. It would be worth booting into BIOS and looking at temperature levels recorded or find of the the system monitoring applications. It could be other critical components or solder joints that also fail after reaching temperature over a period of time.

(Does the system run for a few hours again after rebooting or does it fail quickly - if the latter it would definitely be a heat issue).

The most sensible way to isolate it is to swap components - but this might be costly for you - though it is a fairly old system (5 years??) from what I see from the models quoted.

Comment: Yes, PC is about 4 years old. it runs for few hours.